# How do I display a wrapped json string?

Tags: json, reactjs, word-wrap

I am making a proof-of-concept React app that retrieves data from the GitHub api. The app displays the data retrieved from GitHub as a json string inside a paragraph element.

#### Problem

The json string doesn't wrap. It overflows to the right on several lines.

[image: json string overflowing to the right]

#### What I want

Wrapping on each "word" doesn't make sense, because json doesn't really have words. I want the string to break before individual characters overflow.

#### What I've tried

- Variations of `word-wrap`, and `overflow-wrap`
- Variations of `text-overflow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The json string doesn't wrap. It overflows to the right on several lines.

### Solution

The property/value combo that wound up working was [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

```
<p style={{wordBreak: 'break-all'}}>{JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
```

[image: json string breaking over several lines]